# Is It Possible To Pass A regex to the 'rspec` Command line command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

When calling `rspec` from the command line, I know that you can use the `-e` or `-example` flag to pass in a regex which it matched against the content of any `it` blocks, but is there a way to pass in a regex and have RSpec run files whose names match that regex?

Comment: How complex does the regex have to be? Can you just use bash filename expansion? (or are you not on a *nix os?)

Comment: @bundacia Yep. Could use Bash.

Comment: this is when running all tests or specific files or both?

Comment: What you want ? to run files as per the pattern ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I would like to run any specs whose files contain a word or phrase.

Comment: @dax I'm looking for a way to run any specs with a given word or phrase in the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use for examples :-

> *It will load for you all files, whose names start with `test`*

```
rspec -P spec/**/test*_spec.rb
rspec -P spec/**/test*.rb
```

> *It will load for you all files, which has a word `test` in middle, but not start with `test`*

```
rspec -P spec/**/*?test*_spec.rb
```

It will run all files whose name start with *test*. Like *test_1_spec.rb*, *test_2_spec.rb* etc. But you have to run this command from your project *root* directory.

[Docs for -P / --pattern flag](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/pattern-option)

Information can also be obtained from `--help`

```
arup$ rspec -help | grep PATTERN
 -P, --pattern PATTERN  Load files matching pattern (default: "spec/**/*_spec.rb").
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use bash expansion. It isn't as powerful as a full regex but works most of the time. So you can do things like

```
rspec spec/models/user_*.spec
```

Docs here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching